# Why on installing windows software on playonlinux brackets gets uninstalled?

Tags: wine, uninstall, playonlinux, adobe-brackets

Every time I install *playonlinux* and then on installing windows software when *playonlinux* automatically installs *wine*, *Brackets* gets uninstalled.

The command

```
sudo apt install brackets
```

is unable to install *Brackets*.

However on using the command

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install brackets
```

it says

*My system may be at risk upon installing, if I understand what I am doing I may proceed using the command*

```
sudo snap install brackets --classic
```

Upon giving this command it successfully installs *Brackets*.

But again if I install another windows software again *Brackets* gets uninstalled and I have to again install *Brackets* using `snap` command.

So why this happens?

I do not remember the exact *terminal* error prompt.

Also why my system may be at risk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after following the instructions given by @karel I was facing lots of bugs in Brackets. For example error in Live Preview and problems in installing extensions and themes.

I uninstalled Brackets snap package by

```
sudo snap remove brackets
sudo snap refresh
```

Then I installed Brackets via ppa by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/brackets
sudo apt update
sudo apt install brackets
```

Now everything is working just fine. Also there is no longer any conflict with Playonlinux.

Answer (score 3):

Brackets gets uninstalled every time you install Windows software on PlayOnLinux because of a permissions issue that occurs because Brackets snap package was not installed correctly to begin with. The correct commands to install the Brackets snap package are:

```
sudo apt install snapd  
sudo snap install brackets --classic
```

Note that a snap in classic confinement behaves as a traditionally packaged application with full access to the system.

If Brackets fails to open again after installing Windows software on PlayOnLinux, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt upgrade  
sudo snap refresh
sudo snap revert brackets  
sudo snap refresh brackets  
setsid brackets
```

Comment: Please explain me why my system may be at risk?

Comment: snap command gives the prompt only for brackets, not for any other software.

Comment: snap packages have options for different confinement policies that can be selected when installing the snap package. The default option is a standalone installation which doesn't allow full access to the system and therefore has the most confinement  and the highest level of security. Brackets is an open source, cross platform founded by Adobe and designed for Windows, and it needs some extra access to the system to work properly in Linux.

Comment: When updating system using sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade do snap packages also get upgraded? If not how to upgrade them?

Comment: All snap packages are automatically upgraded in the background by default separately from apt packages. It is also possible to upgrade snap packages manually from the terminal using a command of the form `sudo snap refresh brackets` The  refresh  command  updates the specified snaps, or all snaps in the system if none are specified.

Comment: My Brackets continued behaving abnormally. I uninstalled it and installed it via ppa. Now it is working absolutely fine. What may be the reason? By abnormal, I mean problem in live preview, problem in installing extensions and so on.

Comment: That would be caused by just plain bad packaging if I'm not mistaken.